# How to add vertical scroll in bar chart in chartjs, only when we have more data than space

Tags: scroll, chart.js, bar-chart

I have created a bar horizontal chart in chartjs and want to add a vertical scrollbar when more than 5 data, then add scroll in chart automatically. it is showing scroll but i want scroll within the chart, and only need to show 5 records, rest records in scroll.

I have tried so far...

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
 let data1 = [{
      label: 'Notebook',
      backgroundColor: '#0360b8',
      data: [399,309,278,239,235, 203,182, 157, 149, 144, 143, 137, 134, 138, 118, 107, 127, 137]
    }, {
      label: 'Pen',
      backgroundColor: '#579ee2',
      data: [112, 211, 232, 232, 203,182, 157, 149, 144, 143, 231, 286, 234, 345, 321, 306, 399, 403]
    }, {
      label: 'Papers',
      backgroundColor: '#97c5f5',
      data: [399,309,278,239,235, 203,182, 157, 149, 144, 143, 137, 134, 138, 118, 107, 127, 137]
    }];

    let myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('divchart'), {
      type: 'horizontalBar',
      data: {
        labels: ["Division 1", "Division 2", "Division 3", "Division 4", "Division 5", "Division 6", "Division 7", "Division 8", "Division 9", "Division 10", "Division 11", "Division 12", "Division 13", "Division 14", "Division 15", "Division 16", "Division 17", "Division 18"],
        datasets: data1
      },
      options: {
    responsive: true,
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
            },
   gridLines: {
                display:false
            }
          }],
     yAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                display:false,
    
            }   
        }],
        },
       
  legend: {
                display: true,
                position: 'bottom',
                
            },
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
      }
    });
    
 });
```

```css
.chartheight{height:250px; overflow-y:auto;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<div class="chartheight">
      <canvas class="" id="divchart"></canvas>
     </div><!-- end xol-xs-12 div -->
```